# How to convert a mpeg4-aac video to mpeg-ts using MEncoder?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, aac, mencoder

I know this can be done using FFMpeg and I have done it. The only problem here was that FFMpeg actually tries to "encode" the file while converting to mpeg-ts which I don't want.

i.e. I just want to change the container format to mpeg-ts without encoding the media.

Is this type of conversion possible with FFMpeg? (I know about "copy" option, but it works with H264-aac and not with mpeg4-aac).

Is it possible to change mpeg4-aac to mpeg-ts container format with MEncoder?

I wish to know the personal opinion/advice of those who have already worked on such stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `ffmpeg -i infilename -f mpegts -vcodec copy -acodec copy outfile.ts` ?  If so, how does it not work?  Does it fail, does it try to re-encode the video, or does it produce an unplayable video?